# destroy android fragment and all the child views

Tags: android, fragment

I have an android application with **1** `activity` with **7** `fragments`. Each `fragment` has a `listview` with 100-150 views.

The app runs some services and is all day running, once a day the app crashed with an internal kernel error:

```
 JNI ERROR (app bug): weak global reference table overflow (max=51200)
Last 10 entries (of 51200):
    art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:129]     51199: 0x18d4fe20 android.view.render node
```

seems like a memory leak due to too many views generated by the app.

I think the problem occurs when I regenerate the fragments with all the views, it seems like the views are not completely destroyed.

When I regenerate the fragments for update the data I use this approach:

`for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                }`

There is a method to destroy the fragments and all the view instances inside?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

if use viewPager:

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.removeAllViews();
            viewPager = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception E) {
    }
}
```